# Mostrar imagem mobile quando existir

Tags: css, layout-responsivo, media-queries

Olá,

Tenho um `CMS` próprio e codifiquei uma funcionalidade para permitir, além do upload de imagem de tamanho padrão, uma segunda imagem `mobile` que será mostrada com media query quando a resolução for menor que `768px`, para isso inclui a classe "mobile". Hoje o sistema continua mostrando a imagem padrão, ajustando-a responsivamente com `bootstrap`.

No momento que eu publicar essa funcionalidade em ambiente de produção gostaria que as imagens que já existem e estão no ar, continuassem funcionando com o responsivo e somente quando existir uma imagem mobile, ela seja apresentada no lugar.

Veja abaixo o html e css simplificado

```
<div class="container-image">
    <img src="caminho da imagem padrão" class="show"></img>
    <img src="caminho da imagem mobile" class="show mobile"></img>
</div>

div.container-image img.mobile { display: none; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    div.container-image img.show {
        display: none; 
    }
    div.container-image img.show.mobile   {
        display: block; 
    }
}
```

Minha dúvida é, existe uma maneira de fazer isso sem usar `javascript`? Lembrando que é um `CMS` e todo o `html` está gravado no banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

As imagens antigas também são envolvidas pelo `div.image-container` (imagino que não, pois o seu código já funcionaria)? Caso sim, você pode simplesmente usar uma outra classe (e.g. `image-responsive-container`) para essas novas imagens responsivas; assim os seus novos estilos não vão se aplicar às antigas imagens e você pode criar versões mobile das imagens que já estão no sistema aos poucos.

Comment: Ótima colocação ctgPi, acredito que irá solucionar meu problema. Eu estava desconfiado que era mais um problema de estruturação do que realmente css e js. Obrigado.